# Unity launcher placement doesn't change

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, launcher

I am using double monitors in Ubuntu 14-04 with Unity and I want to change the launcher to my left screen. I know I can find this option in Settings -> Display but when I try to change it, it only changes in the Display configurations screen. The launcher continues in the right monitor. Then I close the Display screen, I reopen it and the launcher continues configured to appear in the wrong monitor.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMkA9.png]

I click 'Apply' and nothing changes

Comment: What technique do you use for multiple monitors? I mean do u have got a docking station, a video adapter or just one graphic card which supports two monitors? I have got same problem with a docking station and a notebook. The monitor directly connected to the notebook supports the launcher. However if I want to move the launcher to the monitor that is connected to the docking station, the setting won't apply.